# Creation of temporary tables and joining them

Tags: sql-server

I need to create two temp tables and later join them together. Does anyone know how to do it correctly?

Here I provide the code that I am using for SQL Server Management Studio. If someone knows how to join them together, I will greatly appreciate!!

```
SELECT s.DEAGY AS 'AGENCY', l.cmschn AS 'MASTER_CHAIN', s.DECHN AS 'CHAIN', s.DESTR AS 'STORE NUMBER', s.DEWEDT AS 'WK_ENDING',
CASE
WHEN s.DEAGY = 10 AND s.DECHN = 'WM' AND s.DESTR IN (1, 9999, 99999) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
END AS WALMART_CONSOLIDATE,
CASE 
WHEN s.DEIO='O' THEN s.DEQTY ELSE '0'
END AS OB_UNITS,
CASE
WHEN s.DEIO='I' AND 'WALMART_CONSOLIDATE'='N' THEN -1 * s.DEQTY ELSE 0
END AS RET_UNITS,
CAST (isnull( 
     ( CASE WHEN s.DEIO='O' THEN s.DEQTY ELSE 0 END ) 
    , 0) AS int) 
- 
CAST (isnull( 
     ( CASE WHEN s.DEIO='I' AND 'WALMART_CONSOLIDATE'='N' THEN (SELECT -1 * s.DEQTY FROM SMPDTA.SMPDTLM) ELSE 0 END )   
     ,0) AS int) AS 'NET_UNITS',
CASE
WHEN s.DEIO='O' THEN s.DERSP ELSE '0'
END AS OB_BILLING,
CASE
WHEN s.DEIO='I' AND 'WALMART_CONSOLIDATE'='N' THEN -1 * s.DERSP ELSE 0
END AS RET_BILLING,
CAST (isnull( 
     ( CASE WHEN s.DEIO='O' THEN s.DERSP ELSE 0 END ) 
    , 0) AS money) 
- 
CAST (isnull( 
     ( CASE WHEN s.DEIO='I' AND 'WALMART_CONSOLIDATE'='N' THEN (SELECT -1 * s.DERSP FROM SMPDTA.SMPDTLM) ELSE 0 END )   
     ,0) AS money) AS 'NET_BILLING',
CASE 
WHEN s.DEIO='O' THEN s.DERPRC ELSE 0
END AS OB_MSRP, 
CASE
WHEN s.DEIO='I' AND 'WALMART_CONSOLIDATE'='N' THEN -1 * s.DERPRC ELSE 0
END AS RET_MSRP,

CAST (isnull( 
     ( CASE WHEN s.DEIO='O' THEN s.DERSP ELSE 0 END ) 
    , 0) AS money) 
- 
CAST (isnull( 
     ( CASE WHEN s.DEIO='I' AND 'WALMART_CONSOLIDATE'='N' THEN (SELECT -1 * s.DERPRC FROM SMPDTA.SMPDTLM) ELSE 0 END )   
     ,0) AS money) AS 'NET_MSRP',
CASE
WHEN s.DEIO='O' AND 'WALMART_CONSOLIDATE'='Y' THEN -1 * p.DEQTY ELSE 0
END AS RET_UNITS,

p.PDQSLD AS 'POS_UNITS',

p.PDQSLD * p.PDRSP AS 'POS_BILLING',

p.PDQSLD * p.PDRPRC AS 'POS_MSRP',

p.PDQOH AS 'Retailer_on_hand_units'
```

This needs to be a temp table

```
FROM REPIT.SMPDTA.SMPDTLM s
JOIN REPIT.LEVYDTA.LDSCHNM l
ON s.DEAGY=l.CMAGY AND s.DECHN=l.CMCHN
JOIN LEVYDTA.SMPRTNM sm
ON s.DEAGY=sm.DEAGY AND s.DECHN=sm.DECHN
where (s.DEWEDT='20210731');
```

Then this needs to be a new temp table

```
FROM REPIT.LEVYDTA.POSDTLM p
JOIN REPIT.LEVYDTA.LDSCHNM l
ON p.PDAGY= l.CMAGY AND p.PDCHN = l.CMCHN
Where p.pdwedt = ‘20210731’
```

Then I need to join the two temp tables together based on

```
s.DEAGY=p.pdagey AND s.DECHN=p.pdchn AND s.DESTR=p.pdstr AND s.DEWEDT=p.pdWEDT
```

Comment: Welcome to dba.SE - please see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: There is no difference to joins using temp tables or permanent tables. You simply use the correct name in the JOIN. I see a very concerning mixture of 3-part and 2-part names - but a different issue. Perhaps you don't need to create temp tables at all?